# Pointers to member data conversion

Tags: c++, pointers

```
struct Base1 {
    int value1;
    Base1() : value1(1) {}
};

struct Base2 {
    int value2;
    Base2() : value2(2) {}
};

struct Derived : public Base1, public Base2 {};

void func(int Derived::*pmf, Derived *d)
{
    printf("%d\n", d->*pmf);
}

void func2()
{
    Derived d;
    int Base2::*b  = &Base2::value2;
    func(b, &d);
}

int main()
{
    func2();
}

Output is 2
```

Hello everyone.
I am reading a book [Inside the c++ object model](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201834545), pointers to member data chapter. There is a code given on the picture, where pointer to data member of a second base class is passed to a function, that expects a pointer to a member of a derived class. I don't really understand what happenes behind the scenes there. It does not make much sense to me such a convertion, especially if you think in terms of pointers to classes, where such thing is not allowed, unless explicit cast is used, although in the book it says that the compiler will adjust the pointer passed to a function. 
So my two questions are:

1) what happens behind the scenes in this situation.

2) If it is just that the compiler adjusts the pointer, is it always the case that compiler knows types of the pointers, and there is no way when pointer type is not known until runtime?

**Update:** Fixed the code and added initial values to value1 and value2.
After the call of a func2() the output is '2', which is the Base2::value2, so apparently compiler did adjust the pointer.

Comment: Post code as plain text, not as images.

Comment: I think it misses something, just that code does not make so much sense

Comment: Edited a question. Replaced image with code.

Comment: Post tested code.

Comment: Jeez, I have no idea what that code even means; are you sure you've transcribed it accurately?

Comment: ...Well, I've fixed the code so it compiles (I switched from `class` to `struct` to avoid visibility issues and fixed the typo on the `pd` parameter). Still not entirely sure what's going on here.

Comment: @Kyle Thank you for help. Transcribed right from the book, and it works, exactly how it is said in the book it should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Behind the scenes, the compiler stores a pointer to data member as an integer offset into the class object.  (I'm ignoring virtual base classes for the sake of simplicity.)

So the line `int Base2::*bmp = &Base2::val2;` looks under the hood like initializing a number to zero, since `val2` is at the start of `Base2`.

When you pass `bmp` to `func`, the compiler implicitly converts from the type `int Base2::*` to the type `int Derived::*`.  This is allowed and safe because anything that is a member of `Base2` is also a member of `Derived`.  But the `Base2` subobject of `Derived` is (probably) not at the beginning of `Derived`, so the offset needs to be changed when doing this conversion.  If we suppose that the `Base2` subobject begins 4 bytes into a `Derived` object, the behavior under the hood would look like adding 4 to `bmp` when it gets passed to `func`.

All `func` does, then, is add the offset it received to the address represented by the pointer `d` to find the `int` member being dereferenced.

> If it is just that the compiler adjusts the pointer, is it always the case that compiler knows types of the pointers, and there is no way when pointer type is not known until runtime?

There is no such thing as a pointer type that is not known until runtime.  Every variable has a type known at compile time.  (Polymorphism doesn't directly come into play with pointers to data members.)

Comment: It seems like the reverse conversion, from `int Derived*::` to `int Base*::`, should *never* work--is that correct? (I was completely unaware of this language feature until seeing this question, so please excuse me if that question doesn't make sense.)

Comment: @KyleStrand A conversion from `int Derived::*` to `int Base::*` is allowed only by an explicit cast and can lead to undefined behavior if used to access a member that is not actually in the object.

Comment: Well, that makes sense. (I generally assume that explicit casts are all-powerful and can achieve any nonsensical conversion, so I suppose I probably shouldn't have emphasized the word "never".) Thanks.

Comment: Now everything makes sense. Thank you for help